# How do I setup Autofac such that it can pass a registered component as an argument to another component?

Tags: autofac

I have

```
builder.Register<ISomething>(c => new Something()).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

what would this look like in Autofac if `Something` took an argument that was an interface also resolved by Autofac?

```
builder.Register<ISomeInitializer>(c => new SomeInitializer()).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.Register<ISomething>(c => new Something(????)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to pass any special argument to your services then you can just write:

```cs
builder.Register<SomeInitializer>().As<ISomeInitializer>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.Register<Something>().As<ISomething>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

In this case Autofac will instantiate your `SomeInitializer` with its default constructor and it will instantiate your `Something` with passing in the `SomeInitializer`.

In you want to keep your current code you can use the `c` parameter (which is an `IComponentContext`) to resolve your dependencies:

```cs
builder.Register<ISomeInitializer>(c => new SomeInitializer())
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.Register<ISomething>(c => new Something(c.Resolve<ISomeInitializer>()))
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```